# Subscribe to all changes of instances of the model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I'm using this example:

https://djangochannelsrestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/model_observer.html

I'm displaying all the data from model `Post` on the page in the table. I decided to use websockets for this and stuck on this issue:

If I'm changing/adding/deleting instances of model using django admin panel - all works fine, but if I'm doing changes by hand in the shell or my celery worker updating the database - then nothing happens, what can be an issue?

My code so far:

consumers.py

```
from djangochannelsrestframework import permissions
from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.mixins import ListModelMixin
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer

from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer


class PostConsumer(ListModelMixin, GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):

    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permissions = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    async def connect(self, **kwargs):
        await self.model_change.subscribe()
        await super().connect()

    @model_observer(Post)
    async def model_change(self, message, observer=None, **kwargs):
        await self.send_json(message)

    @model_change.serializer
    def model_serialize(self, instance, action, **kwargs):
        return dict(data=PostSerializer(instance=instance).data, action=action.value)
```

my template:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Code with SJ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="card">
          <p class="card-header">Display list of all the posts in Real-Time</p>
          <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table align-middle mb-0 bg-white">
              <thead class="bg-light">
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Author</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="post in posts">
                  <td>
                    <p class="fw-normal mb-1">[[ post.title ]]</p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span
                      class="badge rounded-pill d-inline"
                      :class="{'bg-success': post.status !== 'Draft', 'bg-warning': post.status === 'Draft'}"
                    >
                      [[ post.status ]]
                    </span>
                  </td>
                  <td>[[ post.author ]]</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
    <script>
      vueApp = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        data() {
          return {
            posts: [],
          };
        },
      });

      var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/");

      ws.onopen = function (e) {
        ws.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            action: "list",
            request_id: new Date().getTime(),
          })
        );
      };

      ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        allData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (allData.action === "list") {
          vueApp.$data.posts = allData.data;
          vueApp.$forceUpdate();
        } else if (allData.action === "create") {
          vueApp.$data.posts.push(allData.data);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


STATUS = (
    (0, "Draft"),
    (1, "Publish"),
    (2, "Archive"),
)


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="blog_posts",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

No errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: Add your model code

Comment: My first though is that shell and celery work as separated process and thats why observer is not called. But i see that in the example they use shell for updates and it should work.

Comment: @monio I've add model code/